# Removing ground hum safely

Tags: audio, electronic-music, grounding

At church we have a strong ground hum since we added a sound desk into the PA equipment. We have eliminated ground hum on the foldbacks by running them off the same power circuit as the desk. However this is not possible to do with the main front of house speakers.

What can I do to eliminate the ground hum cleanly and safely from front of house?

Comment: Ideally, you would want single-point grounding which you could achieve with some simple modifications and a little knowledge of electronics. But I would just try [user21078's answer](https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/41392/14770), as that would probably do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only use balanced audio connections between several devices with their own power supply and grounding.  If you are using decent equipment, chances are that they already have balanced line input/outputs with TRS 1/4" connectors (quarter inch jacks in tip-ring-shield configuration).  If you connect those with *mono* cables, namely with TS plugs (tip-shield), the sound will still get through but the balancing, along with its insensitivity to ground loops, is gone.  So if you are lucky, just using different cables will get the job done.

If your inputs/outputs are not both balanced, you can balance a connection using a DI box.